# Pass back to exact previous page using php

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I have an events calendar on my website and I want to pass the user back to the previous page. At the moment I'm using several php functions to do it but it isn't passing back to the previous page effectively, I.E. because the previous url uses `&`, it is blocked off of the new hyperlink. Here's what I'm using:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; // Get The URL

<a href=\"event.php?id=$event_id&url=$url\"> // Pass Url To Next Page

if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $backlink = $_GET['url'];
    $user_backlink = "<a href=\"$backlink\"><div id=\"posts\" class=\"sidebarSectionLink sideback\">Back To Results</div></a>";
} else {
    $user_backlink = "<a href=\"events.php\"><div id=\"posts\" class=\"sidebarSectionLink sideback\">Start A Search</div></a>";
}

echo $user_backlink // Link Back to previous
```

The problem is that this only echo's out `http://www.website.co.uk/events.php?type=def`(Nothing else after) - How can I get it to pass the complete url string?

Comment: You could use sessions for that to store URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use urlencode:

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php

So

```
<a href=\"event.php?id=$event_id&url=$url\">
```

Needs to be:

```
<a href=\"event.php?id=$event_id&url=".urlencode($url)."\">
```

End then,

```
$backlink = $_GET['url'];
```

Needs to be:

```
$backlink = urldecode($_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript instead of PHP saves you alot of trouble:

```
<a href="window.history.go(-1);">previous page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using that as an easy solution but some of my visitors are hopefully going to be coming in from social network posts and I'd prefer them to stay on my site rather than being passed back out ;) - So if they come from within my site they go back to the results page, else they go to a new search page

Answer (score 0):

how about this :: javascript+php

```
echo "<script language=javascript> javascript:history.back();</script>";
```

it will work same as the previous button in your browser